# Healpy/Healpix: What is the relationship between the total pixels and total spherical harmonic coefficients?

Tags: python, astronomy, healpy

Based on the Healpy/Healpix documentation, I cannot understand the relationship between one pixel in a sky map (which is some measured value) and the spherical harmonic coefficients produced by Healpy's `healpy.sphtfunc.map2alm` function, which computes an array of the a_lm coefficients for a given map. (This question also applies to anafast.)

My understanding is that a given pixel should correspond to a spherical harmonic coefficient. However, it doesn't. At all.

Take a map with `nside = 8`. This program uses Healpy to read a CMB map in FITS format, manually set the `nside` value, read in the map, display it, and then calculate the spherical harmonic coefficients.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
import pyfits as pf

filename = "cmb_map.fits"    # the name of the full-sky map 

readmap = hp.read_map(filename)   # readmap i.e. input map
nside = 8    # manually input the side value

''' 
Here outputs: 
NSIDE = 8
ORDERING = RING in fits file
'''

view = hp.mollview(readmap)  # view the map, i.e. display it
'''
Shows sky map of the CMB
'''

totalnumberpixels = hp.nside2npix(nside)
print totalnumberpixels      # For nside = 8, this should be 12*nside**2 = 768

arr = hp.map2alm(readmap)    # This is an array of a_lm values
```

So far so good. The `hp.map2alm()` function now returns 300 values, i.e. 300 spherical harmonic coefficients a_lm.

```
arr.shape
```

outputs " (300,) ".

Why would 768 pixels calculate to 300 a_lm values? Is there a mathematical relationship here between `nside` and total number of spherical harmonic coefficients? Does each `nside` give a distinct number of a_lm coefficients?

How many pixels does it take to calculate one a_lm? Any help/explanation is very appreciated!

---

EDIT: 
As discussed below, the total number of pixels is `npix = 12*nside**2`. `map2alm` uses the default `lmax = 3*nside-1`. So, the total number of spherical harmonic coefficients should be the sum of odd numbers up to `3*nside-1=23`. The total number of spherical harmonic coefficients should be (2*lmax+1)**2 = (6*nside-1)**2. (2*lmax+1)^2=(2*23+1)^2 = (47)^2 = 2209. So, where is this number 300 coming from? What exactly is `map2alm` doing? How can this be simply an approximation?

I expect 2209 a_lm. I calculated 300.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no direct relation between a pixel and and the spherical harmonic coefficients.

you can imagine it like this: the map pixels are the data and the spherical harmonic functions you "fit" to the data. The spherical harmonic functions is a system of infinitely many (orthonormal) functions.

Now you do not "fit" infinitely many functions to the data (the pixels), there is limit, you set lmax or mmax or both. (the spherical harmonic functions are usually labelled/identified by two numbers, l and m).

l and m are integers and l goes from 0 to infinity and for each l, m goes from -m to m.

So for instance if lmax is 2 and no limit on m you are dealing with 1+3+5=9 functions. Therefore you will have 9 alm coefficients, (=the results of the "fit"), independently on how many pixels the map has.

Ok so far so good.
Now, the spherical harmonics are complex functions, and the coefficients as well. But the maps is purely real.
So when one reads on Spherical harmonics (Wikipedia is good enough) one will find how to define a real basis of spherical harmonics, basically using the property that Y_l,m=(-1)^m Y*_l,-m , where the star denotes a complex conj.

now if you use complex numbers as the parameters for the function of this basis, how many you need? For given l you will need l+1 complex numbers (remember we count from l=0). And if you sum up to given l you get:

```
l=0 --> 1
l=1 --> 1+2=3
l=2 --> 1+2+3=6
l=3 --> 1+2+3+4=10
etc.
```

(note if you sum up this up to 3*nside-1 you get 300 for nside 8)

also important is to note that for exactly l+1 of these complex coefficients their imaginary part will be zero! (the ones corresponding to Y_l0). Now if you count the number of independent parameters, example for l=3:

```
l=3 --> 1+2+3+4=10
```

so 10 complex numbers = 20 independent parameters. But 4 of them have only real part 20-4=16. Exactly what one expects, because the full imaginary Y_lm has 32 independent parameters, so the real part will have half of that.

Comment: "if it is really a fit or some clever math tricks are involved as well."
This is what I don't entirely understand. I can look at the source code, but I would like a Healpix developer to explain the exact mechanics at work here.

Comment: OK, for the purpose of the explanation you can forget about the "clever math tricks". That is just a technicality and if one would just fit the result will be exactly same, but obtaining/calculating it might take longer. The principle is exactly as I wrote: the map is the data and you fit functions to it; these functions are called spherical harmonic functions. I think what will help you understand the problem is not the code, but reading on what are spherical harmonic functions and what are their properties.

Comment: I'm afraid we might be talking past each other. The l_max defines the number of spherical harmonic coefficients, correct? There will then be a_{l_max}, and the number of m's determined by the l_max such that m, m-1, m-2, .....-m+2, -m+1, -m. Ok, good. We agree here. 
My map is a fits file. It is set at a certain n_side (that determines how the pixels are set). So, what input parameters does the Healpix code take in to give me the number of a_lm coefficients for a given map? Is the l_max determined by the input fits file?

Comment: Ok, according to the Healpy documentation for spherical harmonic transforms `sphtfunc`, the default lmax is set by `3*nside-1`.

Comment: Just edited my answer above to react to the comments. the site suggested that, not sure that is the right way to post it ...

Comment: I finally understand what you mean. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So, as discussed above, the parameter `l_max` determines the number of spherical harmonic coefficients, a_{lm}. For the `l` parameter, the number of a's go from `a_0` to `a_{lmax}`. The `m` parameter is determined by `l_{max}, l_{max}-1, l_{max}-2, ...., -l_{max}+2, -l_{max}+1, -l_{max}`.

So, the total number of `m` values per `l` is given by `2l+1`, e.g. `l=0` gives 1 `m`, `l=1` gives 3 `m`'s, `l=2` gives 5 `m`'s, etc.

The `map2alm` function used by Healpix/Healpy takes in the input parameter `nside`, and then as a default calculates the spherical harmonics using `3*nside-1`.

However, `nside` also determines the total number of pixels per map. The total number of pixels `npix` is given by `npix = 12*nside**2`.

To review:

`npix = 12 * nside ** 2`

`l_max = 3 * nside - 1`

Therefore, the total number of spherical harmonic coefficients is the sum series of `i=0` to `i= 2 * lmax + 1`. Using the default parameter for `map2alm`, this gives us a sum from `i=0` to `i = 6 * nside - 1` (i.e. `2(3*nside-1) + 1`)

For a given map, the total number of pixels is `12 * nside ** 2` and the total number of spherical harmonic coefficients `a_lm` is the sum of `i=0 to i= 6*nside-1`.

Correct?

Comment: The value lmax=3nside-1 is the default value and there are some reasons why, but it is not the only value possible. It can be set to any positive integer. Check the actual value of lmax. It is often set by the developer to a lower value than the default. For instance for nside=512 I use lmax=256

Comment: @AsenChristov I understand that lmax=3nside-1 is only the default value, and it can be changed. My question is "I expect map2alm to calculate a larger number of alm values than it does. Why?" Understand what I mean? Based on the default parameter lmax=3nside-1, I expect to get (47)^2=2209 alm values. I don't. I get 300. For nside=16, I expect to get (6*nside-1)^2=(95)^2=9025. I don't. I get 1176 alm values. This is using the default parameter lmax.