# Healpy map2alm function does not return expected number of alm values

Tags: healpy

`healpy.map2alm` computes an array of alm values for an input Healpix map.

The function is

```
healpy.sphtfunc.map2alm(maps, lmax=None, mmax=None, iter=3, pol=True, use_weights=False, regression=True, datapath=None)`
```

The parameter `lmax` determines the number of alm coefficients. One sets the input `lmax` and the code returns '(lmax+1)**2` number of alm coefficients.

`l=0` returns `a00`.

`l=1` returns `a11, a10, a1-1` + `a00`, i.e. 4 coefficients.

`l=2` returns `a22, a21, a20, a2-1, a2-2`, i.e. 5+3+1 = 9 coefficients. That is `(lmax+1)**2 = 3**2 = 9` coefficients.

However, using `healpy`, this is NOT the output I get, irrespective on the map I chose.

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
nside = 16                         # healpix nside parameter

filename = "cmb_fullsky_map.fits"  # generic name for sky map

readmap = hp.read_map(filename)    # read in the map

# We then use healpy.map2alm(readmap) to generate an array of alm values

ell0 = hp.map2alm(readmap, lmax = 0)    # lmax = 0 should output a00
ell0.shape                              # 1 value
print "l=0 has " + str(len(ell0))
print ell0

ell1 = hp.map2alm(readmap, lmax = 1)    # lmax = 1 should outputs
ell1.shape                              # a11, a10, a1-1 
print "l=1 has " + str(len(ell1))       # 3 values
print ell1

ell2 = hp.map2alm(readmap, lmax = 2)    # lmax = 2 should output
ell2.shape                              # a22, a21, a20, a2-1, a2-2
print "l=2 has " + str(len(ell2))       # 5 values
print ell2

ell3 = hp.map2alm(readmap, lmax = 3)    # lmax = 3 should output 
ell3.shape                              # a33, a32, a31, a30, a3-1, a3-2, a3-3
print "l=3 has " + str(len(ell3))       # 7 values
print ell3

ell4 = hp.map2alm(readmap, lmax = 4)    # lmax = 4 should output
ell4.shape                              # a44, a43, a42, a41, a40, a4-1, a4-2,
print "l=4 has " + str(len(ell4))       # a4-3 a4-4
print ell4                              # 9 values

ell32 = hp.map2alm(readmap, lmax = 32)  # lmax = 32 should output
ell32.shape                             # (lmax+1)**2 = 33**2 = 1089 coefficients
print "l=32 has " + str(len(ell32))     # 65 values
```

My output is not what I would expect by (lmax+1)**2.

```
l=0 has 1
[  2.39883065e-06+0.j]
l=1 has 3
[  2.39883065e-06 +0.00000000e+00j   4.49747594e-06 +0.00000000e+00j
  -5.39401197e-07 +1.07974023e-06j]
l=2 has 6
[  2.38695037e-06 +0.00000000e+00j   4.49747594e-06 +0.00000000e+00j
  -2.93559509e-05 +0.00000000e+00j  -5.39401197e-07 +1.07974023e-06j
  -1.75256654e-05 -1.57729954e-05j   1.65489261e-05 -1.41571515e-05j]
l=3 has 10
[  2.38695037e-06 +0.00000000e+00j   4.51148696e-06 +0.00000000e+00j
  -2.93559509e-05 +0.00000000e+00j   1.19817810e-05 +0.00000000e+00j
  -5.37909950e-07 +1.07783971e-06j  -1.75256654e-05 -1.57729954e-05j
  -7.17416081e-06 +9.14176685e-06j   1.65489261e-05 -1.41571515e-05j
  -2.64725172e-06 -3.09988314e-05j  -7.25462692e-06 -6.33251313e-07j]
l=4 has 15
[  2.38534350e-06 +0.00000000e+00j   4.51148696e-06 +0.00000000e+00j
  -2.93586471e-05 +0.00000000e+00j   1.19817810e-05 +0.00000000e+00j
  -1.72252485e-06 +0.00000000e+00j  -5.37909950e-07 +1.07783971e-06j
  -1.75253044e-05 -1.57728790e-05j  -7.17416081e-06 +9.14176685e-06j
  -1.30606717e-05 -4.21675061e-06j   1.65464103e-05 -1.41578955e-05j
  -2.64725172e-06 -3.09988314e-05j   1.09072312e-05 +3.22054569e-06j
  -7.25462692e-06 -6.33251313e-07j  -1.10079209e-06 +9.39495982e-07j
  -8.01588627e-06 -8.03762608e-06j]
l=32 has 561
```

Do you see the discrepancy?

For `lmax=0`, I expect a total of 1. `healpy` outputs 1

For `lmax=1`, I expect a total of 4. `healpy` outputs 3

For `lmax=2`, I expect a total of 9. `healpy` outputs 6

For `lmax=3`, I expect a total of 16. `healpy` outputs 10

For `lmax=4`, I expect a total of 25. `healpy` outputs 15

For `lmax=32`, I expect a total of 1089. `healpy` outputs 561

Question: Should I act together outputs in order to get the correct total number of arrays?

Please how `map2alm` executes this operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Healpy/Healpix: What is the relationship between the total pixels and total spherical harmonic coefficients?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812976/healpy-healpix-what-is-the-relationship-between-the-total-pixels-and-total-sphe)

Comment: @AsenChristov You're right, but this question explains better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to symmetry. `m=-1` and `m=1` have the same transform, so HEALPix considers only `m>=0`.

So for example `lmax=2` we have:

- a00
- a10
- a11
- a20
- a21
- a22

6 coefficients total.

The length of the `alm` array is expected to be: `mmax * (2 * lmax + 1 - mmax) / 2 + lmax + 1)`.

Comment: Thank you for the help!
What is the recommended way to use `healpy` to output `m<0` coefficients to an `alm` array? My understanding is that Healpix code stores complex alm in an array that has two dimensions to contain coefficients for positive and negative m values. Then l,m maps into the array's index.

Comment: `m<0` coefficient are the same as `m>0`

Comment: I understand now. a_lm is the same value as a_l(-m). a11=a1-1, a21=a2-1, etc.

Comment: Question: does `hp.map2alm` output the a_lm coefficients in a certain order? I would guess the output array is `[a_00, a_10, a_11, a_20, a_21, a_22, a_30, a_31, a_32, a_33,....]`, correct?

Comment: there is a function that gives the order, check in the documentation, I cannot look now.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was looking through the documentation for Healpy/Healpix F90 subroutines. Unfortunately, I could only find how to set the pixel ordering scheme, though this should not affect `map2alm`. I'll keep looking.

Comment: The function to use is `healpy.sphtfunc.Alm.getidx(lmax, l, m)`. From this, we can see the default output is of the order e.g. `lmax=2` the six output values are of the order `(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2,2)`
For  `lmax=4`, the 14 output values are of the order
`(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (2,2), (3,2), (4,2), (3,3), (4,3), (4,4)`

Comment: This order can be written as (for lmax = 4) :
`(0,0), (1,0), ..., (lmax, 0), (1,1), (2,1), ...., (lmax, 1), ..., (2,2), .... (lmax, 2), ..., (3,3), ...., (lmax, 3), ...., (lmax, lmax)`

Answer (score 0):

I has also recently come across this problem. `Healpix` give all the positive `m` values. The negatives can be found with `a(l,m1) = -a(l,-m)*`, where `*` is the complex conjugate.